# Center Align contents of a ListView in react native

Tags: ios, css, listview, react-native

I have used a ListView to list some items but they're all left aligned. How to center align them without using another View wrapping the ListView?

**Code for the ListView**

```
<ListView
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
   renderRow={this.renderItem}
   style={styles.listView}
/>
```

**ListView Styling**

```
listView: {
   paddingTop: 20,
   paddingBottom: 20,
}
```

How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can solve this by using the `contentContainerStyle` ListView prop to apply the needed flexbox styles directly to the ListView's internal container, like so:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={this.renderItem}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.listView}
/>

// ...    

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
   listView: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
   },
});
```

Likewise, this also works when you need both axes centered by adding `alignItems: 'center'` to the `listView` style.

Comment: Adding to this, I came to this question searching how to center items on my horizontal FlatList when there were not enough items to fill the width of the screen, and this worked great. However, when the list filled up, the list could not be scrolled to either side, but kept refocusing to center when pulled. I solved this with a conditional on the `contentContainerStyle` where it would only add this if number of elements is smaller than the number of elements that can fit on the screen. I.e., if 4 elements fit on your screen, do `contentContainerStyle={elements.length < 4 && styles.listView}`

Answer (score 5):

this.renderItem should be a function which renders the row. Your row should set the styles it needs. So something like this:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={this.renderItem}
  style={styles.listView}
/>

renderItem: (item) {
  <ItemRow item={item} />
}
```

And then in the ItemRow component:

```
render: () {
  <View style={flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}>
    <Text>{this.props.item.name</Text>
  </View>
}
```

Comment: Hi @eyal83, yeah that was works if you use the View to add the style. I just wanted to know whether it is possible to add the alignment to the ListView it self. Thanks anyway. Cheers.

Comment: View style needs {{ instead of {